# Есть массив let arr = ['пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб', 'вс']; как можно в консоль вызвать "пн" и "ср"

Tags: javascript

```
let arr = ['пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб', 'вс'];
 function week() {
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.log("пн");
console.log("ср");
```

Если без шуток, то что вы имеете в виду? Вот это?

```
let arr = ['пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб', 'вс'];
console.log(arr[0]);
console.log(arr[2]);
```

```
function myFunc(index) {
    return arr[index];
}
```

Comment: нужно использовать  myFunction( 1 ) , myFunction( 5 ) в место arr но как не знаю

Comment: @user423168 Легко. Дай пять сек ответ обновить

Comment: @user423168 Готово.

Comment: console.log(myFunction (1)) ?

Comment: @user423168 вт............

Comment: consol is not defined

Comment: @user423168 У вас опечатка ­— замените consol на console ;)

Comment: let  arr = ['пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб', 'вс'];
function myFunc(index) {
    return arr[index];
}
console.log(myFunction(1) )?

Comment: @user423168 `let arr = ['пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб', 'вс']; function myFunc(index){ return arr[index]; } console.log(myFunc(1) )`

Comment: спасибо вы supper !

Comment: как можно сделать чтоб  myfanc(1) = 'пн' а не 'вт'

Comment: @user423168 `function myFunc(index) {
    return arr[index-1];
}`

Answer (score -1):

```
let day = ['пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб', 'вс'];
    function myFunc(current) {
      if (current === 1) {
        alert(day[0])
      }
      if (current === 2) {
        alert(day[1])
      }
      if (current === 3) {
        alert(day[2])
      }
      if (current === 4) {
        alert(day[3])
      }
      if (current === 5) {
        alert(day[4])
      }
      if (current === 6) {
        alert(day[5])
      }
      if (current === 7) {
        alert(day[6])
      }
    }
    myFunc(1)
    myFunc(5)
```